# Is there any way to refer, nonspecifically, to every value in a map without using a loop? C++

Tags: c++, qt, dictionary

I have a map (well, a QMap, but I'm guessing if std:map has this functionality QMap will as well) and I want to access every single value in it at once (in order to call a function on all of them. Specifically, I'm trying to access QWidgets and call `setVisible(false)` on all of them).

I could use a loop or an iterator or some such thing, but seeing as I don't need any specificity in which values I need and that I just need to call the same, simple function on them, I was wondering if there's a function or anything that lets you access every value.

Comment: What's wrong with a loop? Especially considering the handy [ranged `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) (which works very well together with type deduction using `auto`).

Comment: If you don't want to write the loop yourself, you could also use `std::for_each`

Comment: NB: If the widgets have the same parent, you can hide that parent

Comment: You could always write a visitor for associative containers, but at the end of the day there will still be some form of looping. It's just a question of how hidden that loop is. If it bothers you to write a loop, feel free to hide it behind a function or object. Future maintainers might disagree with you about that decision though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have upper limit for the number of elements, then you don't need a loop to call a function on all elements of a map:

```
auto map = init_map();
auto it = std::begin(map);
if(it != std::end(map))
    (it++)->second.setVisible(false);
if(it != std::end(map))
    (it++)->second.setVisible(false);
if(it != std::end(map))
    (it++)->second.setVisible(false);
if(it != std::end(map))
    (it++)->second.setVisible(false);
if(it != std::end(map))
    (it++)->second.setVisible(false);
if(it != std::end(map))
    (it++)->second.setVisible(false);
if(it != std::end(map))
    (it++)->second.setVisible(false);
if(it != std::end(map))
    (it++)->second.setVisible(false);
```

This works with maps up to 8 elements. This is quite silly however, and can be greatly simplified by using a loop. You don't have to write the loop yourself though, since you can use `std::for_each` provided by the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if there's a function or anything that lets you access every value.

There are some options ( and more as given here ) which makes it a one liner, but all results in a loop, may or may not later behind the function call.

1)
STL provides `std::for_each`

2)
but a simple loop makes it more convenient at all with `for ( auto& x: m ) { x.second.Do(); }`

Full example:

```
struct X
{
    int i;
    void Do() { std::cout << "Do called" << i << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<int, X> m;

    m[1]=X{10};
    m[3]=X{30};
    m[4]=X{40};

    std::for_each( m.begin(), m.end(), []( auto& x){ x.second.Do(); });

    // looks nicer for me:
    for ( auto& x: m ) { x.second.Do(); }
 }
```

Internally all results in a loop, maybe compiler will optimize and unroll if content of map is known and compiler is very clever.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [`ranges::view::values`](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html#range-views) to get at each second element of a sequence of pairs.

E.g.

```
QMap<Key, QWidget *> items; // filled somehow

auto widgets = items | ranges::view::values | ranges::view::indirect;
std::for_each(widgets.begin(), widgets.end(), [](auto & widget){ widget.setVisible(false); });
```